# org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

i am getting this error when I want to run the following code:

```
package HIndexSaar.HIndex;

public class AppHibernate {

public static void main(String[] args){
    HibernateManager mng = new HibernateManager();
    mng.addPerson("H H", "Uni Saarland");
    mng.addPerson("Bernd Finkbeiner", "Uni Saarland");
    mng.addUniversity("Saarland University");
    }
}
```

My HibernateManager class:

```
package HIndexSaar.HIndex;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateManager {

private static SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public HibernateManager(){
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new   StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        ourSessionFactory =     configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * adds a person to the database.
 * @param name: the name of the person
 * @param affiliation: the university of the person
 * @return the created ID
 */
public Integer addPerson(String name, String affiliation){
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer personID = null;
    try (Session session = ourSessionFactory.openSession()) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p = new Person(name, affiliation);
        personID = (Integer) session.save(p);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return personID;
}

/**
 * adds a university to the database.
 * @param name: the name of the university
 * @return the id of the newly created university
 * */
public Integer addUniversity(String name){
    Transaction trans = null;
    Integer uniID = null;
    try (Session session = ourSessionFactory.openSession()) {
        trans = session.beginTransaction();
        University uni = new University(name);
        uniID = (Integer) session.save(uni);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (trans != null) {
            trans.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return uniID;
}

/**
 * adds a publication to the database.
 * @param name: the name of the publication
 * @param author: the author of the publication
 * @return the generated ID
 */
public Integer addPublication(String name, String author){
    Transaction trans = null;
    Integer pubID = null;
    try (Session session = ourSessionFactory.openSession()) {
        trans = session.beginTransaction();
        Publication p = new Publication(name, author);
        pubID = (Integer) session.save(p);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (trans != null) {
            trans.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pubID;
}

}
```

And my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory name="HIndex Session">
   <!--  Database connection settings -->
   <property name="connection.driver:class">org.postgreSQL.Driver</property>
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/HIndex</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">index_user</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
   <!--  JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
   <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
   <!--  SQL Dialect -->
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <!--  Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
   <!--  Names the annotated entity class -->
   <mapping class="HIndexSaar.HIndex.Person"/>
   <mapping class="HIndexSaar.HIndex.University"/>
   <mapping class="HIndexSaar.HIndex.Publication"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>HIndexSaar</groupId>
 <artifactId>HIndex</artifactId>
 <version>Version 0.2</version>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>HIndex</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1207</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

The error is shown at the "tx.rollback();" line:

```
catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I do not use multiple threads anywhere, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `ResourceClosedException`:

> Indicates an attempt was made to use a closed resource (Session,
>   SessionFactory, etc).

Now, when using "try with resources", the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) says:

> Note: A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks
>   just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources
>   statement, any catch or finally block is run **after the resources
>   declared have been closed**.

So by the time you call `rollback()` the `Session` will already have been closed.

The simplest solution here would be to move your existing catch block to an **inner** try/catch block around the transaction-management code, e.g.:

```
try (Session session = ourSessionFactory.openSession()) {
    try {
       tx = session.beginTransaction();
       Person p = new Person(name, affiliation);
       personID = (Integer) session.save(p);
       tx.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
             tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the `Session` only gets closed once you've (at least) requested rollback.